# How can we add a divider between the table rows in table flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've to add a Divider line between three TableRow, how can we add? Because it says: The element type 'Divider' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'

Comment: wrap TableRow with Table and add border attribute

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this way , if you want only bottom line.

```
body: Table(
      border:
          TableBorder(bottom: BorderSide(), horizontalInside: BorderSide()),
      children: [
        TableRow(children: [
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
        ]),
        TableRow(children: [
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
          Icon(Icons.access_alarm_outlined),
        ])
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

##### If you want dividers on every row, just use the border property

```
Table(
   border: TableBorder(horizontalInside: BorderSide())
   children: []
)
```

##### If you want to be able to insert a divider at will into the table, you can use this builder:

```
TableRow buildTableRowDivider({
  required int cols,
  double height = 1,
  Color color = Colors.grey,
}) =>
    TableRow(
      children: [
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
          Container(
            height: height,
            color: color,
          )
      ],
    );
```

e.g.

```
final tableRowDivider = buildTableRowDivider(cols: 3, height: 2);

Table(
  children: [
    ...otherRows,
    tableRowDivider,
    ...otherRows,
  ],
);
```

Just set the number of columns in your table, and you can customize the height and color as you like.

All it does is build another TableRow but filled with color

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't return a divider to Table row. But you can do similar. Wrap your TableRow with Table and add border property.
Run this code and see how it is working.

```
Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
          children: [
            TableRow(children: [
              Text('Cell 1'),
              Text('Cell 2'),
              Text('Cell 3'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              Text('Cell 4'),
              Text('Cell 5'),
              Text('Cell 6'),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will give the desired output. Only condition is that the two lists must have the same length:

```dart
class MyTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> title;
  final List<double> value;
  const MyTable(this.title, this.value, {super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTable> createState() => _MyTableState();
}

class _MyTableState extends State<MyTable> {
  const double tinyTextSize = 12;
  const double smallTextSize = 20;
  static Color mainColor = Colors.blue;
  var divider = const TableRow(children: [
    Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10), // here we make some space on 
        child: Divider(
          color: mainColor,
          thickness: 2,
        )),
    Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10), // both sides for elegant UI.
        child: Divider(
          color: mainColor,
          thickness: 2,
        )),
  ]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Table(
                defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                  0: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                  1: IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                },
                children: List.generate(
                    widget.title.length * 2 - 1,
                    (i) => i & 1 == 1 // if odd we add the divider
                        ? divider
                        : TableRow(children: [
                            Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.title[i ~/ 2],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: tinyTextSize),
                                )),
                            Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: Text("€${widget.value[i ~/ 2].toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: smallTextSize))),
                          ])))));
  }
}
```

using it:

```
List<String> titles = ["Buy me a coffee if you liked it", "Just kidding an upvote will do"];
List<double> prices = [2.65, 6.5];
[...]
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyTable(titles, prices);
```